# Get unique results from JSON array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have this block of code that displays the "categories" from my array into a JQuery simple list.

It works fine, but if there are 3 items from the category "basketball", the category will appear 3 times.

How could I make it so they only appear once ? Thank you.

Here's the code :

```
function loadCategories() {
    console.debug('About to refresh with sort type : ' + sortType);
    var items = [];

    $.each(catalog.products,
        function(index, value) {
            items.push('<li id="' + index + '">' +
                  '<a data-identity="productId"  href="./productList.page?category=' + value.category + '" >' +
                  '<p style="margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:0px;">' + value.category + '</p></a> </li>');
        }
    );

    categoryView.html(items.join(''));
    categoryView.listview('refresh');
}
```

Here's the code for my array :

```
var catalog = {"products": [
{"id": "10001",
"name": "Mountain bike",   
"color": "Grey/Black",
"long-desc": "12-speed, carbon mountain bike.",
"description": "",
"size": "20 inches",
"category": "Outdoors/ Equipment rental",
"sport": "Cycling",
"brand": "DaVinci",
"top-seller": ""},

{"id": "10002",
"name": "Pro Multi Basketball",   
"color": "Rainbow",
"long-desc": "On sale this week only! This limited edition basketball is multi-coloured, and offers pro performance. Fun and games on the court!",
"description": "Limited edition basketball.",
"size": "N/A",
"category": "Team gear",
"sport": "Basketball",
"brand": "Nike",
"top-seller": "x"},
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't know how your `products` array is built up (so my example might need some modification according to your needs), but you could write a little piece of code that will first collect your unique categories into a new array:

```
var categories = [];

$.each(catalog.products, function(index, value) {
    if ($.inArray(value.category, categories) === -1) {
        categories.push(value.category);
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3wHfB/)

`categories` will hold the unique categories you need, you can use it to build your HTML from that (be careful with the IDs of those `li` elements though, remember that IDs cannot be duplicate, you might give them a little prefix).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work..  I'll keep you posted. I edited my question with the code from my array if you have time to look into it. Thanks again.

Comment: @JFFF I loaded your example object into my code: [jsFiddle Demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/3wHfB/3/). Seems to work for me. Feel free to tweak my fiddle to get the result you expect (maybe you want to add additional values into the `categories` array).

Comment: hello, is there a way to make it unique for any other field, so lets say (using the categories json) that you want all the colors without any duplicates.

Comment: @Djeroen Yes there is, you simply have to change the code a bit. I suggest you play with the code, understand it, then you will see it is easy.

Answer (score 4):

How to get unique values by property

```
function groupBy(items,propertyName)
{
    var result = [];
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
       if ($.inArray(item[propertyName], result)==-1) {
          result.push(item[propertyName]);
       }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Usage

```
var catalog = { products: [
   { category: "Food & Dining"},
   { category: "Techonology"},
   { category: "Retail & Apparel"},
   { category: "Retail & Apparel"}
]};

var categoryNames = groupBy(catalog.products, 'category');
console.log(categoryNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var catalog={
    products : [
        { category: 'fos', name: 'retek' },
        { category: 'fos', name: 'item' },
        { category: 'nyedva', name: 'blabla' },
        { category: 'fos', name: 'gihi' },
    ]
};
console.log(_.uniq(_.map(catalog.products, 'category')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

Use [_uniq](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq)