# Check if object does not exists in array, and if not push to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Okay, I've tried several examples found on stackoverflow on my example and nothing worked for me as I wanted. I have an array with 12 object in it which looks like this

```
var buttons = [ {"tag":"adr","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"ag","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"fax","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"ind","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"sname","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"per","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"tel","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"url","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"url","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"weblink","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"weblink","color":"#123456"},
           {"tag":"close","color":"#123456"} ];
```

and I wanna push this to another array `var buttonsP` if it is not in that array already. I tried (among other examples) with jquery `.grep` option:

```
var buttonsP =[];

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){

    var newObject = { "valueTagP": buttons[i].tag, "colorTagP": buttons[i].color };    
    if( $.grep(buttonsP, function(obj) { return obj.valueTagP != buttons[i].tag; }) ){
        buttonsP.push(newObject);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < buttonsP.length; i++){
    $(".list").append("<li>"+ buttonsP[i].valueTagP + ", " + buttonsP[i].colorTagP +"</li>");
}
```

But duplicates were not removed.

You can check and edit my situation here: http://jsfiddle.net/M4mA9/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Cerbrus That did not work for me because I have objects in array, not values. I've tried to modify just that example but I lost myself

Comment: Plz check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680430/get-unique-results-from-json-array-using-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.grep` will return the matched array based on the condition. You see the details at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/

Your code should be like

```
    var newObject = { "valueTagP": buttons[i].tag, "colorTagP": buttons[i].color };   
    var newArr = $.grep(buttonsP, function(obj) {             
        return obj.valueTagP === buttons[i].tag; 
    });
    if(newArr.length === 0) {
        buttonsP.push(newObject);
    }
```

I modified your code and updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4mA9/1/)

Comment: that will work for me, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming **buttonsP** contains only **buttons**.

In that case,

instead of making buttons an array, make it an object as

```
var buttons = {key : "some_unique_key",
               value: /*put your buttons array here*/}
```

now **buttonsP** will contain buttons object (not an buttons array)

Now you can easily find buttons object in your array based on the key (make sure it is unique)
and insert if it is not there.

Answer (score 1):

```
var buttonsP = $.grep(buttons, function (obj, i) {
    var m = buttons.filter(function (v) {
        return v.tag === obj.tag;
    })[0];
    return $.inArray(m, buttons) === i;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f22dv/

Comment: nice example too, but I accepted faster one, don't get mad :)

Answer (score 0):

If you may use JQuery, try it:

```
var a1 = ["Cecilie", "Lone"];
var a2 = ["Cecilie", "Emil"];
var b = $.unique($.merge($.merge([], a1), a2));
```

Comment: `$.unique()` only works for DOM elements. It's used by jQuery internally.

Comment: and yet, it works! http://jsfiddle.net/LfZ55/

Comment: Yes, your demo works, from `$.unique` documentation, "_Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers._" :)