# How to set unique ID for each Item in Android ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, arraylist

My Code:

```
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            if(jArray.length() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    expense_id = json_data.getInt("expense_id");
                    client_name = json_data.getString("client_name");
                    expense_type = json_data.getString("expense_type");
                    expense_amount = json_data.getInt("expense_amount");
                    listItems.add(i, expense_id + "- " + client_name + " | " + expense_type + " : Rs. " + String.valueOf(expense_amount));
                }
                adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
                ListView list_expenses = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_expenses);
                list_expenses.setAdapter(adapter);
                registerForContextMenu(list_expenses);
                list_expenses.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,int position, long id) {
                        final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        final int extra_expense_id = Integer.parseInt(item.split("-")[0]);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreenActivity.this, ViewExpenseActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_EXPENSE_ID, extra_expense_id);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
```

When I use onItemClick listener, I want to send 'expense_id' to the next Activity. But how do I set individual 'expense_id' for each Item?

In my code I've added expense_id in each item and then splitting it to get the id. But this is a bad approach. Any way I can set a hidden ID attribute to each listItem?

I also tried - listItem.add(expense_id, "String object here"); so that I can get the index which would be equal to expense_id.
But this work since ArrayList has to start from index 0.

Possible Answers:
1 - User Custom Adapter: No I've already implemented ArrayAdapter properly.
2 - Use setTag, getTag? That works on entire ListView object. It doesn't work on individual items.

Comment: From your code i can see you are making string using before adding in to your list, so why dont you manage another list only for id, and when user click on item of list get the position and get the id. You have already did bad code so add some more in it.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680430/get-unique-results-from-json-array-using-jquery) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create separate list for expense id.

```
ArrayList<Integer> expenseIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Added expenseId in list in for...loop

```
expenseIds.add(expense_id);
```

You can get expense_id int onItemClick method like below code

```
expenseIds.get(position);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store the ids in a separate list and maintain both.

```
listItems.add(i, expense_id + "- " + client_name + " | " + expense_type + " : Rs. " + String.valueOf(expense_amount));
listIds.add(i,expense_id);
```

and within your item click listener you can get the expense id from the position variable

```
listIds.get(position);
```

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Add a `TextView` to the row and set it value to be the id of the row.

Next, set `visibilty=gone`.

Whenever you require the id, just convert it to `int`.